# Converting Ant Web Application Project to Maven Project

Tags: ant, maven-2

Hi I have a running code project build using Ant now what i need is to convert it to maven , i browse for the solution and what i done is simply creating a new maven web project and added all my src files to src/main/java and all the xml files (e.g security.xml,tiles-config.xml,web.xml,properties files,jsp folder  etc) to webapp/web-inf/ folder. Is that correct so far ??

The main question how to create a pom file , I mean as I used a lot of jar to support the code , how to mention that in my pom file ..Did I have to mention for each one of them ??
Please give an idea ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a script to transition legacy ANT projects to a Maven infrastructure:

- [ant2ivy](https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy)

It focuses on generating a list of dependencies, which the [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) plugin 
downloads from Maven repositories. It is also able to create a local repo for those 5-10% of jar files that can never be identified (nobody remembers who added them into the project...)

This code could be adapted to generate a Maven POM, a piece of work I've been considering. The problem is that it's really hard to switch ANT projects over to Maven in a seamless manner.... Maven has a standardized set of life-cycle actions, whereas ANT build scripts are free-form. This explains why I concentrated on dependency management.