# how to convert pom.xml to build.xml

Tags: java, maven, ant

Am a new bee in this area.

Got a part in pom.xml like below which i need to change in ant buid.xml.

How do i do it? Can i get any help from tutorial or anyone can explain what

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ask.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>wzlogging</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you already have a `build.xml`?

Comment: A POM does not relate to a build.xml file, just as much as Maven does not relate to Ant. However, if you integrate Ivy into your Ant environment you ***can*** convert the POM to an ivy.xml file with the [convertpom](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/use/convertpom.html) task.

Comment: I dont need to convert the whole stuff only that part which i have mentioned above, so <ivy:convertpom pomFile="pom.xml" ivyFile="ivy.xml" /> is not a option for me

Comment: Do you understand what the `<dependency>` element does? If yes, how are you handling dependencies in your current script? If not, here's the documentation: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

Comment: @KarmakarA If Ivy isn't an option please provide further details.

Answer (score 3):

In theory it's possible to generate a ANT build file (using XSLT?), but one would need to understand the logic that each plugin implements. In practice only simple Maven builds are feasible candidates.

ANT and Maven are very different build technologies. In ANT you explicitly write all the build logic into the "build.xml" file. Maven on the other hand has most of it's functionality baked in. The "pom.xml" contains no logic instead is used to document meta information about the project (for example the list of dependencies).

Coming from an ANT world this can be very confusing, especially when you want to customise your build. In Maven this is done by declaring plugins, which understand the standard build life-cycle and are able to insert themselves at the correct part of your build.

The purpose of this long-winded explanation is to understand that it's really impossible to know what your plugin is doing by only looking at the POM file.

@Perception recommended ivy. The following answer is related (Convert from ANT to Maven):

- [Converting Ant Web Application Project to Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083245/converting-ant-web-application-project-to-maven-project/15098916#15098916)

Comment: You can use `mvn ant:ant` to convert the script into equivalent tasks (assuming standard plugins). However, the OP doesn't seem to care about the entire script, just translating dependencies. But whether s/he needs to retrieve the dependency, apply the exclusions, or something completely different is impossible to tell from the question.

Comment: The question asked how to convert from Maven to plain old Apache Ant, which is strictly speaking not possible, because ant does not support project dependency management without Ivy. I do not think any XML transformation could do the trick. The link posted above concerns taking Ant projects to Aaven, which is an entirely different animal (and entirely possible).

Comment: @parsifal I never knew and Maven supported an ant plugin that would allow the user to build the project completely without maven. I'll have to read up om that.

Comment: @parsifal you're correct I'd forgotten the ant plugin (+1). But it only generates a generic build file. It can't look into a custom plugin (which is the exmample given) and derive what it's doing

Comment: @RudolphEst It's feasible to generate an ANT build that incorporates ivy tasks to pull down dependencies. If ivy is not allowed one could in theory have a series of "get" statements.... As I stated in my answer it would only work for very simple Maven files (without plugins), would painful to write and would be a rather pointless exercise :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maven and ant are very different tools.

Ant is a build tool primarily, this means it knows how to compile and package source code and run tests, but has no ability to manage project dependencies. Ant uses build.xml files to define where to find the source code and which steps to take to build your project.

Maven is more than just a build tool, it is a project management tool. It allows you to define dependencies in the pom.xml project definition, as well build, test and distribute the application. It also allows sub projects, parent projects and there exist many plugins for many other features. Maven will automatically download the dependencies and manages these dependencies between projects.

Simply put, it is not possible to just convert a Maven POM project into an Ant build.

There are alternatives that allow binary maven dependencies to be utilized within ant builds. Have a look at the [Ivy dependency manager](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Maven has a useful Ant plugin to generate a Ant build file from Maven pom.xml easily. 
Use this maven goal: mvn ant:ant.

In eclipse: Simple generate another run-configuration for a maven build. Name it "Antfile generate". In field "Goals" Enter ant:ant. Apply these changes to you new run configuration. Typ run to start the build. In console log you get an message

[INFO] Wrote Ant project for PROJECTNAME to .