# How to retrieve data from BigQuery and insert the data to mySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, shell, google-bigquery, sh

I'm trying to write a batch file which can retrieve specific data from Google BigQuery and then insert these data to mySQL.

The language for batch server is Java and the  build tool is Ant.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For reading from Google BigQuery, you can use the [Java Client Libraries for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). Here is the whole [Github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/447813753c3e4191b62e003d8013483f1d2b6265/bigquery) which contains more info. Was this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for the reply  Iñigo. Is there anyway to use Client Library for BigQuery using build tool Ant?  We are not using Maven. That's the problem we have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Iñigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7650339/i%C3%B1igo) mentioned, you can read the data from BigQuery with the [BigQuery Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library). This would be the easiest approach. You have 2 options here:

a.Create a query job to get the result set of a SQL query, parse the result and write it to MySQL. For this approach you can use:

1. The [“Job create”](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#create-com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo-com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.JobOption...-) method to create a query job (see an example
   in the link).
2. The [“getJob”](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#getJob-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.JobOption...-) method to get the status of the asynchronous job.
3. The [“getQuery”](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#getQueryResults-com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId-com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.QueryResultsOption...-) method results method to get the result set.

b.Create an [export job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data), which will export the data of a BigQuery table to a file in Cloud Storage, then, download the file from Cloud Storage and write the data to MySQL. Note this method will be more difficult if you are not familiar to Google Cloud Platform, since you’ll need to create a Cloud Storage bucket and interact with the [Cloud Storage Java library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

To write the data to MySQL you’ll  need to use a Java Connector like [this one](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html).

Hope this points you into the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Mike! It seems like the API requires Maven as the build tool but unfortunately we are not using Maven and the system is using Ant.  Is there anyway to use the API based on the build tool Ant?

Comment: In not so sure about that one, perhaps you can use this [Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/usage.html) to generate an Ant build file. Or use the [Ivy dependency manager](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). You may want to take a look at the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121928/how-to-convert-pom-xml-to-build-xml) which pointed me to that resources.